# How to add link to form action attribute with js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add / append the url to the form action attribute. How do I do this? I have the code below but does not work because I'm using the AHAH(Asynchronous HTML over HTTP) method to load the html form on the page

```
//load submission form
$(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#submit-a-request").load( 'http://draftsite.com/submit-a-request' + ' #item-submission');
}); // ready

//submission form

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#item-submission').attr('action', 'http://draftsite.com');
}); // ready



<form id="item-submission" action="/submit-a-request/maintenance-request/a2db427bfdc794d3695d8ac6843cb04d" method="post" name="submissionForm" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <input type="text" name="elements[0c7f7be5-059b-4cd3-8641-d88f4199af01][0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="255">

    <input type="text" name="elements[bc797942-f95f-438e-ad05-e44b2199e9a8][0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="255">
<

    <textarea name="elements[169f7b63-e778-4a1b-ac22-654c2e248bca][0][value]" cols="60" rows="20">Floor Number /  Room Description</textarea>


    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_zoo">
    <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="submission">
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="save">

    <input type="hidden" name="8958a901f9a45927058aef098665efa5" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: What is "the ahah method"?

Comment: AHAH(Asynchronous HTML over HTTP)

Comment: first 3 lines of jQuery code explains it

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) compete callback

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'http://draftsite.com/submit-a-request' + ' #item-submission'
  $("#submit-a-request").load( url , function(){
     // new html exists, can modify it now
      $('#item-submission').attr('action', function(_, action){
           return 'http://draftsite.com' + action;
      });
  });
}); // ready
```

Comment: thanks,  but how do I keep "/submit-a-request/maintenance-request/a2db427bfdc794d3695d8ac6843cb04d"  and add the http://draftsite.com at the beginning?

Comment: not sure what you are asking, seems you left some details out of question

Comment: if you look in the form you will see "/submit-a-request/maintenance-request/a2db427bfdc794d3695d8ac6843cb04d"  I want to keep that there and add http:// draftsite.com

Comment: so you just want to add a different domain in front? Use `attr('action', function(_, action){ return 'newDomain.com' + action`;})`

Answer (score 0):

Please find this snippet there is an extension method for add and append attribute you can achieve this by  **[jQuery.fn.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/)**  please check it will surely helpful to you

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  AddAttribute: function(attr) {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).attr("action",attr)
    });
  },
  AppendAttribute: function(attr) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var existingattr= $(this).attr("action");
      $(this).attr("action",attr + existingattr)
    });
  }
});


$(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#submit-a-request").load( 'http://draftsite.com/submit-a-request' + ' #item-submission' , function() {
  //Add attribute
  $('#item-submission').AddAttribute('http://draftsite.com');
  //Or append Attribute
  $('#item-submission').AppendAttribute('http://draftsite.com');
});
}); //
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="item-submission" action="/submit-a-request/maintenance-request/a2db427bfdc794d3695d8ac6843cb04d" method="post" name="submissionForm" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <input type="text" name="elements[0c7f7be5-059b-4cd3-8641-d88f4199af01][0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="255">

    <input type="text" name="elements[bc797942-f95f-438e-ad05-e44b2199e9a8][0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="255">



    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_zoo">
    <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="submission">
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="save">

    <input type="hidden" name="8958a901f9a45927058aef098665efa5" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: why do all this when jQuery core already has these capabilities built in?

Comment: i don't recommend to write the same code again and again so it's clearly cool if we are creating common extensions for this as per my point of view